# updating textview in an infine loop after specified time interval

Tags: android

```
private void eastablish_connection(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    make();
    while (check)
    {

        if ( th == null)
        {
            make();
        }
            th.start();
            try
            {
                th.join();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("failed", "joining");
            }
            set();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try
            {
                th.join();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("failed", "joining");
            }
            th.interrupt();
            th = null;
```

}

```
public void set()
{
    fridge1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    fridge1.setText("indoor = " + my_connection.get_indoor_temperature());
}
public void make(){
    my_connection = new Make_Connection();
    th = new Thread(my_connection);
}
```

what i need is to update my text View continuously after completion of thread but it is not showing anything at all.the set function is called properly but it doesnt showing anything.?.please help

Comment: is my solution worked out? if it is correct then accept!

Comment: i found another way of doing that by countdowntimer class ..i will surely try your way also

Answer (score 0):

You can't have infinite loop in the UI thread. You see nothing on the screen because your UI thread is locked in your infintie loop.

If you want to perform an action every X seconds, you can use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple logic....

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
    }).start();

Handler h = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        textView.setText(text);
    }

};
```

Just register your handler class with thread and update your textview in handler class after thread sleeps 3 sec.

Comment: that works good ..but how can i keep running that thread until main thread is destroyed i.e User close the app.I have tried to set that in loop but it is not working with that and "out of memory" exception is thrown..?

Comment: For that you can use count down timer or timer or service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Handler h=new Handler();
    Runnable runn=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update text view here
            h.postDelayed(runn, 2000);
        }
    };


    private void startUpdating() {
        h.postDelayed(runn, 0);
    }
```